# CheckBox not highlighting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I am selecting any Row the checkboxes aren't getting highlighted. Sometimes even if I selected any row then every rows gets selected automatically. I am using Material UI Table in ReactJs

```
const headCells = [
  {
    id: "sl_no",
    numeric: true,
    disablePadding: false,
    label: "Sl_no",
  },
  {
    id: "business_code",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: false,
    label: "Business_Code",
  },
```

//removed most columns soo as to post the question easily but can refer to image for the column names

```
function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
  const {
    onSelectAllClick,
    order,
    orderBy,
    numSelected,
    rowCount,
    onRequestSort,
  } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            color="primary"
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{
              "aria-label": "select all desserts",
            }}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "normal"}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <Box component="span" sx={visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </Box>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}
export default function EnhancedTable() {
 
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
  const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
      setSelected(newSelecteds);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };

  const handleClick = (event, name) => {
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(name);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    setSelected(newSelected);
  };


  const isSelected = (name) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

  // Avoid a layout jump when reaching the last page with empty rows.
  const emptyRows =
    page > 0 ? Math.max(0, (1 + page) * rowsPerPage - rows.length) : 0;

    
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Paper sx={{ width: "100%", mb: 2 }}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            sx={{ minWidth: 750 }}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={dense ? "small" : "medium"}
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              
                 rows.slice().sort(getComparator(order, orderBy)) */}
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.sl_no)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.sl_no}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox
                          color="primary"
                          checked={isItemSelected}
                          inputProps={{
                            "aria-labelledby": labelId,
                          }}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        id={labelId}
                        scope="row"
                        padding="none"
                      >
                        {row.sl_no}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="center">{row.business_code}</TableCell>
                      
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow
                  style={{
                    height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows,
                  }}
                >
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        
      </Paper>
      
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This is how the the invoice table looks

[image: Invoice Table]

Comment: Can you please post your code in a code snippet along with some sample HTML?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I am really sorry about that.. I am new to ReactJS soo I don't really know which part to just share

Comment: Speaking generally, to get better answers post a minimal example of your code that highlights the problem. But definitely include your code in a snippet or a code block and not in a link, so that if others come along and see your question it won't matter if the code at your link still exists / has changed